# Autolayout - adding and running constraint

Tags: ios, nslayoutconstraint

I have a view with 2 container views: one main one on top and one at the bottom.

When the app launches, the bottom one is hidden via a frame that goes beyond the screen height. The top one in the meantime occupies the entire app window.

When I decide to show that bottom container, I want the top container to decrease in height and the view of the controller in that main container to be impacted as well.

I tried to add a constraint programmatically and used layoutIfNeeded but nothing worked.

I'm new to this. I don't necessarily want the best answer but how I should approach this.

Thanks!!!!

```
-(void)showBottom {
    NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.bottomContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.mainContainer attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:49.0f];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];
}
```

Comment: Show how you are adding the constraint

Comment: So I want to call that method and have the constraint be applied. Not sure how I do this. This method is within the controller whose view holds the 2 containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try pinning objects with a `Top Space to Superview` constraint and animating it.

```
// .h
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topConstraint;

// .m
[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
    self.topConstraint.constant = 0;
    [self.nView layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: Do I need an animation for this? Can't I just do what I did above and then call layoutIfNeeded?

Comment: You can but it will just appear suddenly.

Comment: Thanks. Still having trouble with it. Will keep at it

Comment: Actually I have tried something else where I reassign the frame. It seems to work. Now my problem is that a table view from a controller embedded in the main container gets cut off and doesn't readjust. Have to figure that one out.

Comment: Found a way by adding a constraint via the storyboard on the table view and the bottom of the view.